# How to update text save to database in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, uitextview

I have UITextView for write notes. After writing notes then click done button text will save to database. After i add some more text continue from old text then click done button it saves new row of text.

Table:

```
 texts               texts_id
    Hi                    1
   Hi, How are u?         1
```

First i wrote Hi text and click done. Then i query from database for texts and wrote How are u? but it saves new row? I need to replace first row with Hi,how are u? Is it possible?

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT textnotes FROM textnote where textnote = '%@','%@',",txtview.text,artID] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        BOOL favExist = false;

        sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                favExist = true;
            }
        }


        if(!favExist){


            const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into textnote (textnotes,text_id ) values ('%@','%@')", txtview.text,artID] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"sql insert is %s",sqlInsert);

            // [catID release];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing an "UPDATE" statement, instead of an insert.

On the first "Done" click, your code is fine, but on subsequent clicks of the "Done" button, where you would like to update the row, you need to use something like this.

```
const char *sqlUpdate = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update textnotes set text = '%@' where id = rowID", txtview.text,rowID] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I hope that makes sense to you. When you insert, you are simply adding a new row. It also looks like your 'id' column is not an AutoIncrement, as it should be so that the row ID does not repeat.